# Multivariate Chebyshev nodes

Tags: numpy, polynomial-approximations

The Chebyshev nodes prevent Runge's phenomen when determining polynomials. For the interval `[0, 1]` the Chebyshev nodes of second type can be determined by `(1 + math.cos(math.pi * (1 + (i-1) / (n-1)))) / 2` with `i=1..n`.

Is there a multidimensonal version which distributes the points "optimally" on a multidimensional simplex?

I've been looking into numpy's chebyshev module, but didn't get the connection to the nodes.

Comment: [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182675/multivariate-polynomial-interpolations) is a related Question on MathOverflow and in [this paper](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~potts/paper/nonperiodicR1L_a4.pdf) is a pseudo algorithm for constructing a rank-1 chebyshev lattice.